# Issue with thumbnail images in slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I want show thumbnails on slick carousel. Here is my initialization code:

```
$('.regular').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children().length > 1) {
    $this.slick({
      dots: true,
      arrows: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      navs: true,
      customPaging: function(slider, i) {
        return '<div class="thumbnails">' + $(slider.$slides[i]).find('img').prop('outerHTML') + '</div>';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here, I try to show the images in a  list (shown [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/qMuVqj2Mm4xW)).

Is there any way to show the images as a carousel so that it will show only the first 4 thumbnail images?

Comment: Instead of using 'custom paging', output all your thumbnail images into a separate div and then initialise slick on that aswell. Then you're effectively running two slick sliders, one for the main images and one for the thumbnails. Then you can sync both sliders together as shown below in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for slide syncing, something like:

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
  margin:3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="slider slider-for">
    <div>
     <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>4</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>5</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div>
     <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>4</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <h3>5</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: thanks , also when i try your cod using             

      `<div class="slider slider-for">
       <div>
       <img  src=<?php echo' "'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'"   '?> /> 
       </div>
       </div>
      <div class="slider slider-nav">
      <div>
       <img  src=<?php echo' "'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'"   '?> /> 
      </div>   
      </div>`
          
 i get this result https://www.screencast.com/t/UBtXW1otM

Comment: the problem is that plugin use an array of images using <img src=<?php echo' "'.JURI::root().$image->file_url.'" '?> />  also i don't knwo how to see them on the snippet.

Comment: also if it not possible to fix it , is there any way to show only 4 images using  `customPaging: function(slider, i) {
        return '<div class="thumbnails">' + $(slider.$slides[i]).find('img').prop('outerHTML') + '</div>';
      }`

Comment: you could show only 4 server side, better than do it client-side

Comment: ok i have installed it here https://dev.allhidaya.com/en/ you can see when you click on the quick view icon  https://i.imgur.com/3JK7RiR.png